# pasar toggleClass dentro de función each en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

El objetivo es que al hacer click sobre un li (generado por append) quede con la clase activada y luego al hacer click nuevamente se elimine la clase.
Pensé en toggleClass, pero está contando todos los each.

```js
$('#write').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) { // enter key bb
 var value = $('#write').val();
 if ($(this).val().length === 0) { // bla bla
  }
 else {
  $('.result').append('<li class="doit">' +value+ '</li>');
  }
 $('#write').val(''); // reset value :D
 // ===========================================================
 // so far so good
 
   
  
  
  // Problem here
  $('.doit').each(function(){
   $(this).on("click", function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active'); // problem skip one (1+2+3)
   //$(this).addClass('active2'); // I need a toggle function!
  });
  // Problem here
  
  
  

});
 }
});
```

```css
#write {
  padding:20px;
  color:white;
  width:300px;
  background:#161d2e;
  height:30px;
 border:0px;
  
}
.result li:hover {
 cursor:pointer;
}
.result li {
 width:320px;
  height:15px;
  background:#161d2e;
margin-top:2px;
 color:white;
 padding:10px;
 
}
.active {
 background:green !important;
}

.active2 {
 background:red !important;
}
li {
 list-style:none;
}

body {
 font-family: Arial;
 background:#959595;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="write" type="text" placeholder="write here and press enter" />
<div class="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/damocosodo/1/edit?js,output)

Esto te debe solucionar tu problema si agregas las clase `active` al crearlo y después poder desactivar y activar el elemento `li` con la función `.toggleClass()`.

```
$('#write').keypress(function(e) {

    if (e.which == 13) {

        var value = $('#write').val();

        if ($(this).val().length === 0) {

        } else {

            $('.result').append('<li class="doit active">' +value+ '</li>');
        }

        $('#write').val('');
    }
});

$(document).on("click", '.doit', function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```